# Laravel Session Expiring on Login 5.5 GCS

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, session, google-cloud-sql

I've got a problem with my live version of laravel 5.5. I've deployed laravel to google cloud and it's giving me an error when I log in:

```
The page has expired due to inactivity. 

Please refresh and try again.
```

Now this is only on the live version. The local development version is working fine, connected to the google cloud mysql database i've set up. I can log in there and the database is correctly storing a session in the session table.

The live version is connected to the database as my home page is pulling a random column from the database to prove its connecting.

A little confused. I've tried many things including file sessions but nothing is working. Any ideas. I can supply whatever is needed i just dont know what to attach so if you need more info i will supply :)

---

### Added to hopefully help

## app.yaml

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

skip_files:
  - .env

env_variables:
  # Put production environment variables here.
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_DEBUG: true
  APP_KEY: base64:5da/VZbwRMdsa45Y5ti4r/dVf9I6EaTFu/HILySr0idU=
  STORAGE_DIR: /tmp
  CACHE_DRIVER: database
  SESSION_DRIVER: database

  ## Set these environment variables according to your CloudSQL configuration.
  DB_HOST: my ip
  DB_DATABASE: database
  DB_USERNAME: user
  DB_PASSWORD: password
  DB_SOCKET: "correct cloud socket"

beta_settings:
    # for Cloud SQL, set this value to the Cloud SQL connection name,
    # e.g. "project:region:cloudsql-instance"
    cloud_sql_instances: "correct cloud instance"
```

## .env

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:kKDP4OIvWo13ghoUHzwLeKGX2GsSOhsdf3SU+z9nM=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=database
SESSION_DRIVER=database
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=Myip
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: What session driver are you using in production?

Comment: SESSION_DRIVER: database (but i have also tried file and set the storage folder to 775) still no luck

Comment: Ok, I assume you've set it as the driver in the .env file and run the migrations to create the session table?

Comment: Yes. I have ran the create the session table using php artisan on the google cloud mysql database and my local development laravel instance is populating that table when i log in on that. I then migrate that the the live server but it wont create anything in that session table when i log in and comes up with the page expire message above

Comment: I am using the app.yaml for the live version. Let me post them in the original question for you to see

Comment: Are you passing a CSRF token? ({!! Form::token() !!})

Comment: Yes, im using the built in auth functionality and the form contains: {{ csrf_field() }}